# Imperfecto del subjuntivo describiendo un evento real

Tags: gramática, subjuntivo, tiempo

¿Está bien dicha la siguiente pregunta?

> ¿De qué estábamos hablando antes de que se cortara la llamada?

El uso del imperfecto del subjuntivo me parece extraño en este contexto, dado que la cortada tuvo lugar, no era prevista, y además porque "de qué estabamos hablando" no dependía de ninguna manera de ella. Usar "cortó" en vez de "cortara" me parece más correcto. Sin embargo, se lo he preguntado a varios amigos hispanoparlantes y están totalmente de acuerdo en contra de mi opinión.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coincido con tus amigos en que lo correcto es usar el subjuntivo.

Según la Nueva Gramática de la RAE, [puntos 24.9i al 24.9k](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=SGUZAkDawmpPpiHm):

> **24.9i** (...) Las partículas [*antes* y *después*] coinciden con *cuando* y *mientras* en rechazar los futuros y los condicionales, pero (...) neutralizan en un gran número de contextos los tiempos simples (*antes de que muera*; *después de que amaneciera*) y los compuestos (*antes de que haya muerto*; *después de que hubiera amanecido*). Por otra parte, ***antes* se construye con subjuntivo**, pero *después* admite los dos modos (...).
>
> **24.9j** Si V1 pertenece a la esfera del presente, en V2 aparece «*antes (de) que* + CANTE o HAYA CANTADO»:
>
> > <sub>**Habrá** muchas más personas infectadas antes de que **remita** la epidemia (*Universo* 8/12/2003); Piensan que no lo **hará** antes de que **haya transcurrido** una hora (Tomeo, *Mirada*).</sub>
>
> **Si V1 pertenece a la esfera del pasado, en V2 aparecen pretéritos imperfectos** o pluscuamperfectos:
>
> > <sub>**Salieron** antes de que **terminara** la comunión (Martínez Salguero, *Combate*); Fueron los únicos periodistas que **tuvieron** acceso a Salinas antes de que el ex presidente **diera** fin a su ayuno (*Proceso* [Méx.] 27/10/1996); Por la mañana se **despertó** antes de que **hubiera amanecido** (Tomás, *Orilla*).</sub>
>
> **24.9k** Se registra en estas construcciones el uso de CANTE por CANTARA (...). En el español general de hoy se prefiere *naciera* o *naciese* a *nazca* en el primero de los textos que siguen, y *entrara* o *entrase* a *entre* en el segundo. **El pretérito imperfecto de subjuntivo es pues, la opción recomendada en ambos casos**, de acuerdo con la correspondencia de tiempos presentada en el § 24.1a:
>
> > <sub>Felisa comenzó a trabajar conmigo justo antes de que *nazca* la más chiquitita (CREA oral, Bolivia); Tanto la compra como el embarque de las unidades se realizaron antes de que *entre* en vigencia el dispositivo (*Caretas* 20/3/1997).</sub>

Tu ejemplo es exactamente el caso anterior: una construcción con *antes de que*:

> ¿De qué **estábamos** hablando ***antes de que*** se **cortara** la llamada?

La acción de referencia V1 es "estábamos", pasado; por tanto, a la acción V2 introducida por "antes de que" le corresponde el imperfecto de subjuntivo.

---

Nótese que, si estuvieras usando *después* en vez de *antes*, entonces el uso que propones sí sería correcto:

> ¿Qué **dijiste** ***después de que*** se **cortó** la llamada?
> ¿Qué **dijiste** ***después de que*** se **cortara** la llamada?

Ambas opciones son válidas (tienes ejemplos en el punto **24.9l** que aparece tras los indicados, en el mismo enlace).

Answer (score 0):

Antes de que siempre indica la expectación de algo en cualquier tiempo aún cuanda tuvo lugar porque en el pasado el telephono no habia sido colgado y estaba solo una posibilidad. Por lo tanto require sujunctivo en todos casos. Del otro lado, después de que solo usa el subjunctivo en el futuro.